# connecting to localhost through android emulator with xampp server

Tags: java, php, android

**running php script through android program with giving localhost address like**

```
try {
        url = "http://10.0.2.2:80/xxx/";
        //optionally I tried
        //url="http://localhost/xxx/";
        //url="http://192.168.1.8/xxx/";
        //url="http://127.0.0.1/xxx/";
        //above all options are not working for me. 
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        request = new HttpGet(url);
        response = httpclient.execute(request);
    }
try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

            // Appending result to textview
            result.append(line);
        }
```

all above url fails to connect even I checked my firewall setting but it's not working.
need help I am stuck in this thread.

Comment: have you getting any error then please post logcat ?

Comment: Are you sure that the web server is being hosted on port 80?

Comment: Anyway, here you have the documentation you need to look at: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: #Harsha Chhelana, sir I am not getting error in program but I couldn't connect through my android emulator.

Comment: Open your android browser and test the link

Comment: are you able to connect to the url from android browser

Comment: @silentw, yes sir I am sure even I checked in firewall setting its open for all user.

Comment: Then next step is checking the connectivity to the computer using the emulator's browser.

Comment: @Indra which link should I check in it?

Comment: @Indra, through android emulator browser I am able to connect internet I mean emulator shows me google as we see in computer screen. even I tried to enter http://localhost/foldername/ in address bar but it shows web page not available.

Comment: It means your local host url is not right. Look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access your local host from your android emulator Use the ip address given in ipconfig.

Open command prompt->type ipconfig-> Get IPV4 address.... something like 192.xx...

[image]

So your URL="http://192.xx.xx.xx/folder/file.php"

Test this url with your android browser.... If it connects then there should be no problem in android app

Comment: I agree with this step as well, I followed your steps to run it, emulator not showing result but when I typed this address manually on emulator browsers address bar its showing me result that is what I want. it might be good idea to check connection !.

Comment: @IceBreakerSandy 10.0.2.2 should do it too.

Comment: @silentw sir it works when I manually enter this into emulator browser address bar..but through program source code its not working. as #Indra says I followed same its good to see connection but how we can make it by our code.

Comment: @IceBreakerSandy  if you are able to connect from browser means then emulator app also should work fine. If not Post your full code of the concerned activity with Logcat errors

Answer (score 0):

For setting up a local testing environment, you can use [localtunnel](https://localtunnel.me/). This application creates a global https server for your local server.

E.g.

lt --port 8080 will create https connection for : localhost:8080/

Comment: I appreciate your advice but I think it will take more time to work on it. I just go through that link even I read all stuff but it seems not easy and I am scare about making such things because what if I made some changes on my machine and if it not work properly. need your support. thanks for good R&D.

Answer (score 0):

finally I tried hard and got success, Here I wish to post my answer with all those guys were completely stuck with such issues.
ok Here I am using this Url Pattern

```
 try {
        url = "http://192.xxx.x.x/xxx/index.php";
        Log.d("url is ", " "+url);
        ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX; 
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp); 
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        request = new HttpGet(url);
        //Log.d("requested url", " "+request);
        response = httpclient.execute(request);
    }
    // response code
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

            // Appending result to textview
            result.append(line);
        }
    }

 adding these lines into AndroidManifest.xml

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

       **Happy Coding to all of you.**
```